# What is the influence of Germanic languages on Esperanto grammar?

Tags: grammar, germanic-languages, dutch, esperanto

I am making a presentation in my class about the influence of Germanic languages on the Esperanto grammar. I was wondering if you could help me further.

I already said that Esperanto was a non pro-drop language and that Germanic languages tend to be also non pro-drop. I found that Esperanto can create very easily compounds and the same goes for German and Dutch. I also found that Esperanto is equally dependent on prepositions as English.

I know that the grammar is very easy to learn, but have you got any other influences on the grammar?

Thanks in advance,
Bruno

Comment: Esperanto is only truly easy to learn if you're already a speaker of a western European Indo-European language — you won't get too much in terms of ease of learning if you started as a monolingual, say, Ndebele speaker.

Answer (score 1):

There is a significant portion of root words derived from Germanic languages, e.g., drinki (to drink alcoholic beverages), trinki (to drink), hundo (dog), jaro (year), verŝajne (probably), bedaŭrinde (unfortunately).

Some of the affixes are Germanic, e.g., -ino (feminine, from German -in as in Lehrerin)

Compounding (as you already noted) is clearly Germanic (and specifically German).

You may also want to ask this question on the [Esperanto Stack Exchange](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com) to get more answers.